# Pull values from a row based on ID

Tags: php, sql

Hoping someone can shed light on this. I am trying to pull the value from 2 fields from a row and based on the row being expired, exclude those 2 values from a drop down list.

I have a table (schedule)
gameID
homeID
visitorID
gameTimeEastern
weekNum

each week there are matchups where 2 teams play each other. Those 2 teams are in a row based on gameID with a specific start time (gameTimeEastern).

I have a function that determines when the matchup is locked, meaning the game has started:

```
function gameIsLocked($gameID) {
//find out if a game is locked
global $mysqli, $cutoffDateTime;
$sql = "select (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) > gameTimeEastern or DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) > '" . $cutoffDateTime . "')  as expired from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule where gameID = " . $gameID;
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    return $row['expired'];
}
$query->free;
die('Error getting game locked status: ' . $mysqli->error);
```

This basically determines if the row is expired (gameTimeEastern has passed). I then have a drop down on a form that has a list of all the teams from each matchup for that week.If the row is expired, then I do not want to include the homeID or visitorID from that row in the drop down.

On my page I am trying to show those teams from the expired row but it is failing as the page stops processing when it hit this:

```
        //get expired teams
    $expiredGames =gameIsLocked(gameID);
//      echo 'Expired games are GAME ' . $expiredGames . '<br>';    
    for ($eti=1; $eti<=$gameID; $eti++)
    {
     if ($gameID[$eti]>''){
    $sql = "select * from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule WHERE gameID = '" . $gameID[$eti] . "';";       
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $expiredHomeTeam = $result['homeID'];
        $expiredVisitorTeam = $result['visitorID'];
    }           

            }
echo 'Expired teams for GAME '.$gameID.' are '.$expiredHomeTeam.' and '.$expiredVisitorTeam.'<br>'; 

}
```

NEW CODE - Actually giving me the first result

```
            //get expired teams
    $expiredGames =gameIsLocked(gameID);

    $sql = "select * from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule WHERE weekNum = '6';";      
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $expiredHomeTeam = $result['homeID'];
        $expiredVisitorTeam = $result['visitorID'];
    }           
        echo 'Expired teams for GAME ' . $expiredGames . ' are '.$expiredHomeTeam.' and '.$expiredVisitorTeam.'<br>';
```

Comment: have you closed your getgameIsLocked function?

Comment: Please post your error message from error_log.

Comment: Had wrong function name - now getting error - Error getting game locked status: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: I just dont think that I am pulling the  "Get Expired Teams" correctly. I know the function (gameIsLocked) works. Confusing myself a little as I have been staring at this for hours.

Comment: I updated the second part of the code. No errors, but not getting any output - the echo statement never happens.

Comment: print your $sql variable (or var_dump it).  Then run the query directly on the database (using some SQL client soft).  Start with this to ensure your query is good, and you get the expected results.

Comment: I am now getting the first result, now need to figure out how to get all the locked game teams, not just the first one

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the SQL query to schedule to get results I needed. Thanks for the direction. The logic was already there, just needed to add an if statement to how I populated the array for teams in the drop down.